How do I call a function of a class that is a part of a kivy ScreenManager
My app has a ScreenManager with a couple of screens. I need to call the create_widgets() function of the SecondScreen. I may need to call it a couple of times while running the program with different variables passed into it.
The creation of the widgets of the SecondScreen is called in the FirstScreen through a button (self.template_btn). There will be a couple of self.template_btn objects (created through a for loop) that will each call the creation of the SecondScreen widgets with different variables.
I thought of just making the widgets in the init function, just as I did in the FirstScreen. But I need my SecondScreen to update itself with each template that is passed to it, not remain constant. If the init function is called when changing the sm.current (which I doubt), then I could just set the current_template to the template that I currently need, then change sm.current to the SecondScreen and then use the current_template to create widgets.
If I could call a function directly then I would just need to pass a variable and work with that, but I don't know how to do that or if that is possible
current_template = None 

def set_current_template(template, allow, screen, *args):
    global current_template
    current_template = template

    if allow:
        app.change_to_screen(screen)
        SecondScreen.create_widgets()

def start_timer():
    return

class YogaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='First'))
        self.sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='Second'))
        self.sm.add_widget(ThirdScreen(name='Third'))
        self.sm.add_widget(FourthScreen(name='Fourth'))
        self.sm.add_widget(FifthScreen(name='Fifth'))
        # self.sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='First'))
        # self.change_to_First()
        # self.sm.current = 'First' # Для того чтобы тестировать шаблоны. УБРАТЬ ПОТОМ
        return self.sm

    def change_to_screen(self, s, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sm.current = s

    def change_to_First(self, *args):
        self.sm.current = 'First'

    def change_to_Second(self, t, *args):
        self.sm.current = 'Second'

    def change_to_Third(self, *args):
        self.sm.current = 'Third'  # I did not want to do it this way

    def change_to_Fourth(self, *args):
        self.sm.current = 'Fourth'

    def change_to_Fifth(self, *args):
        self.sm.current = 'Fifth'

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    """The first screen the user sees. It is the screen for creating a workout or a workout
    template. It also shows all of your created templates which you can click for the second
    screen to pop up
    """
    total_training_sessions = 0
    total_training_sessions_text = 'Всего тренировок: ' + str(total_training_sessions)
    # Это шаблоны тренировок
    templates = {}

    # А это все упражнения
    # exercises = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Creates all widgets and adds them on the first screen. Creates templates that
        are a button with the text of the name and the exercises of the template.
        It does so by extracting the template name and values from the dictionary 'templates'
        
        :param kwargs:
        """
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout_root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, None), padding='10dp')
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
        self.lbl1 = Label(text=self.total_training_sessions_text, size_hint_y=None, height=20)
        # Кнопка, при нажатии которой откроется второй экран
        self.btn_create = Button(text='Создать Шаблон', on_press=partial(app.change_to_screen,'Third'),
                                 size_hint_y=None, height=20)

        # self.btn_create.bind(on_press= изменить sm.current на второй экран)
        self.lbl2 = Label(text='Шаблоны:', size_hint_y=None, height=20)  # , pos_hint={'x': -0.42}

        self.layout.add_widget(self.lbl1)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn_create)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.lbl2)

        from os import listdir, path
        for filename in listdir('templates'):
            with open(path.join('templates', filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                self.template_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, None), padding='10dp')
                self.lbl_name = Label(text=str(filename.replace('.txt', '')), size_hint_y=None, height=20)
                self.template_layout.add_widget(self.lbl_name)
                k = 0  # Считает кол-во упражнений в шаблоне
                while True:
                    exercise_info = file.readlines(2)
                    k += 1
                    if not exercise_info:
                        break
                    num_of_exercise, exercise = exercise_info
                    num_of_exercise = str(num_of_exercise.replace("\n", ""))
                    exercise = str(exercise.replace("\n", ""))
                    text_1 = str(k) + " - " + exercise + " x" + num_of_exercise
                    self.template_lbl = Label(text=text_1, size_hint_y=None, height=20)
                    self.template_layout.add_widget(self.template_lbl)

                self.template_btn = Button(size_hint=(1, 1))
                self.template_btn.bind(on_press=partial(set_current_template, filename, True, 'Second'))
                self.template_layout.add_widget(self.template_btn)
                self.layout.add_widget(self.template_layout)

        self.layout_root.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.add_widget(self.layout_root)

    def create_widgets(self):
        for template in self.templates:
            pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # add template
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Перенёс потому что второй экран скорее всего будут открывать несколько раз
        # И эти несколько раз нужно будет делать всё по новому
        # При нажатии кнопки в первом шаблоне он вызовет функцию которая:
        # 1- вызовет create_widgets второго шаблона с тем шаблоном, кнопку которого нажали
        # в качестве аргумента
        # 2- поменяет текущий шаблон на этот

        # name = 'шаб 1' #УБРАТЬ ПОТОМ
        # for x in template.keys():
        #    name = str(x)
        # self.layout_root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True,size_hint=(1, None))
        # self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        # self.lbl1 = Label(text=name)
        # self.btn_rest = Button()
        # self.btn_start = Button()
        # self.btn_cancel = Button(text='Отмена', on_press=app.sm.switch_to('First'))
        # self.ids['cancel'] = Button()
        # self.ids['layout'].add_widget(self.btn_start) НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
        # self.ids['layout'].add_widget(self.btn_rest)


    def create_widgets(self):
        global current_template
        template = current_template
        name = str(template)
        file_name = str("{}.txt".format(template))

        layout_root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint=(1, 1))
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, None), padding='10dp')
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        upper_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(1, None), padding='10dp')
        lbl1 = Label(text=name, size_hint=(0.7, 1))
        upper_layout.add_widget(lbl1)
        btn_rest = Button(size_hint=(0.3, 1)) #Добавить взаимодействие с 5 экраном
        upper_layout.add_widget(btn_rest)
        layout.add_widget(upper_layout)

        btn_start = Button()
        # btn_cancel = CancelButton()
        # self.btn_cancel = Button(text='Отмена', on_press=app.sm.switch_to('First'))
        # self.ids['cancel'] = Button()
        # self.ids['layout'].add_widget(self.btn_start) НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
        # self.ids['layout'].add_widget(self.btn_rest)
        layout.add_widget(lbl1)
        layout.add_widget(btn_rest)
        layout.add_widget(btn_start)
        # layout.add_widget(btn_cancel)
        layout_root.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(layout_root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = YogaApp()
    app.run()

I tried SecondScreen.create_widgets(some_argument) but it didn't work
I tried k = SecondScreen, k.create_widgets(some_argument) and it didn't work

You must call create_widgets() through the instance of SecondScreen that is part of your App. To do this you can use the get_screen() method of ScreenManager. Try replacing:
SecondScreen.create_widgets()

with:
App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('Second').create_widgets()

in your set_current_template() method.
